# MongoDB keeping data safe

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am making a web app that stores a user note into mongoDB. The problem is that the content is being stored raw (means I can read what the user wrote down). Is there a way for me to keep this information safe? Maybe something like an encryption function in the backend server that mixes up the content before storing to the db, then undo the encrypted content when fetching the data from the db.

I currently am thinking of my method above

Comment: What's the purpose of this? Generally the way you would do something like this is simply access control. Only give people access to what they absolutely need access to. The only semi-secure way to do this that doesn't impact user experience at all would be to encrypt the data on the server side using something like AES-256, then store a key in a secure location that the application can access to decrypt it. There's a saying that I like: "Security is like a door. If nobody is able to get in, then nothing will be able to get out.".

Comment: This web app is like a note taking web app that uses Mongo DB to store the user saved notes basically. Nothing too fancy. I am the only one with access to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that user note is so sensitive, is storing it locally for them an option? If not, then theres a few solutions:

1. Like you suggested, you could encrypt on your backend API before DB insertion and then decrypt on the backend API on retrieval. That would stop you from reading it if checking the database, but since your API owns the keys to that encryption then you can still technically decrypt it and read it.
2. The above solution, but can be better by adding user supplied salting to the key. The problem then is that you have to track and create that salt - and it must be the same each time - on the client side. The client will still have to tell you the salt and trust that you aren't storing it. But then theres always the problem of if you are request logging, you could maybe get the salt to decrypt even if you didnt store it in the database.
3. The best (and only) solution of the 3 to ensure you cant decrypt it is E2E encryption. The encryption keys are created and stored by the user, never transmitted to the server. You can derive it from a password or generate randomly and store it locally etc. The encryption happens before the client sends the data, and the client also decrypts it.

Comment: Solutions 2 and 3 could potentially be problematic as this eliminates a lot of flexibility that comes with having it be a web application. Since this isn't stored on the web server, you would have to use the same browser under the same profile on the same computer every time or not even the server would be able to decrypt the data. The second option has a similar issue in that if you were to use lets say the last couple characters of their password hash for the salt, they wouldn't be able to easily change their password. If they did, you would be required to decrypt and re-encrypt everything.

Comment: Then I might just do the first option for now, and I won't read their files. I don't know much about encrypting data so I will have to look into it later.

Comment: @Jesse is correct in that its not without its issues, but thats the price to pay for privacy - having users control it with all the cons that comes with that